# Принцип создания модели для unity3d?

Tags: unity3d, 3d, blender

Столкнулся с абсолютно новой для себя задачей. Требуется создать некий механизм  использующий поршни, т.е что-то вроде экскаватора. Поэтому вопрос в следующем, достаточно ли будет самой Unity3d для этого или проще будет создать модель в 3д редакторе вроде Blender'a, и если я буду эту модель импортировать в Unity3d, то на что требуется обратить внимание при создании, если я планирую управлять им через клавиатуру?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unity - это игровой движок разработки. 3d модели он делать не умеет - только примитивы вроде кубов, сфер и прочего.

Если их вам достаточно, то будет достаточно и Unity. Если нет - используйте сторонний редактор и импортируйте модели. Формат моделей выбирайте fbx. Там же, в редакторах, можете и анимировать.

Если будете анимировать силоми Unity, то не объединяйте в редакторе все примитивы в один меш, либо нарежте его на те части, которые собираетесь двигать в анимациях.